# How do I get something added to the FAQ?

Tags: support, formatting

I just use the Comms Room to find out how to add formatting to comments. A helpful person there pointed me to https://serverfault.com/editing-help, which I would know if I was asking a question. However, when writing a comment, that doesn't show up.

Proposal: add a pointer to that page on the FAQ, and say "works great for your comments as well!"

Answer (score 1):

When you're typing a Q/A, if you click the "?" icon just to the top/right of the text box, you'll see a link for "Advanced Help" which takes you to that Markdown page (which is woefully incomplete; there's a page on mSO somewhere is a *more* complete list).